# If $X$ is a countable set, does there exist a metric that makes it compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $X$ is a countable set, does there exist a metric that makes it compact? I know there is always a metric that does not make it compact and that there are examples of compact countable spaces but I am unable to figure out if every countable set has a compact metric or not.

Comment: This is equivalent to asking "does there exist a compact countable metric space" (yes there does; Adam Chalumeau gives an example).  As soon as you have one, take any bijection between it and your X, and pull back the metric as in Adam's answer.

Comment: One useful way of defining a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ with a unique limit $x$ is that $x$ is the unique point $y$ such that, for every open set $U$ containing $y$, the set $\{n\in \Bbb N: x_n\not \in U\}$  is finite. Equivalently (in a metric space) $\{x\} =\cap_{m\in \Bbb N}\,Cl(\{x_n:n\ge m\}).$ And  it follows easily that  the subspace $\{x_n:n\in \Bbb N\}\cup \{x\}$ is compact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a countable set $X$. There is a bijection $f:X\to A$ where $$A=\{1/n~\vert~n\geq 1\}\cup \{0\}$$
Give $A$ the metric induced by the metric on $\Bbb R$ (it's just the absolute value). Then define the metric on $X$ by $$d(x,y)=\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert$$
You can check that this is a metric on $X$ and that  with this metric, $f$ is an isometry between $X$ and $A$. Therefore $X$ and $A$ are homeomorphic spaces. Because $A$ is compact, so is $X$.

Answer (score 1):

By similar argument X can be homeomorphic to {1/n : n is natural no. } having usual metric. Then A and this set {1/n : n is natural no. } are homeomorphic.  But the 1st one is compact where 2nd one is not compact.